# awk program from solaris machine gives warnings in linux nawk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, solaris, gawk

I am trying to run the script which was in the solaris in the linux machine.
It's showing warnings  `nawk: cmd. line:7: warning: escape sequence`\<' treated as plain `<'`
I can't change the version of the awk. Is there any other way to remove this warning?

EDIT:
My awk file will simply print the xml tags in function.

```
function PrintExamHeader()
{
 print "<exam";  #I have removed the \ 
}
```

Now it's giving warnings at line number where there is no such pattern.

```
  BEGIN {        # here it's giving warning
   OFS = "";

  # Indexes for series structure
  idx = 1;
  Number = idx++;
  ItDate = idx++;             # and 3 more at such lines 
  Time = idx++;
  Date = idx++;
```

Comment: Can you provide your solaris awk command?

Comment: It's simple printing of xml file  `print "\<exam";`

Comment: Your example code is still inadequate (as an aside: don't comment `awk` code with `//`, use `#`); if you want us to help you, create a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - in other words: something _small_ and _self-contained_ - code _plus_ input data - that _produces the symptom_.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress warnings ?

Comment: Yes, you can categorically suppress _stderr_ output - where the warnings are sent - with this redirection: `2>/dev/null`. The caveat is that this would also suppress genuine error messages. However, genuine failure is also reflected in `awk`'s exit code: if it's _nonzero_, an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example that triggers the warning (GNU `awk`; on some Linux systems, `nawk` is a symlink to GNU awk, `gawk`):

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "\<exam" }'  # -> '<exam'
```

If your output is OK, and all you need to do is to **get rid of the warning, simply remove the `\`**:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "<exam" }'  # -> '<exam'
```

If instead you wanted to print `\<exam`, you'd have to *double* the backslash:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "\\<exam" }'  # -> '\<exam'
```

What the **warning is trying to tell you is that the `\` prefix is essentially a no-op *in this context*, and that it is not needed**.

Comment: I removed all the \ but in some places it's still giving warnings. I checked the line number but no such pattern exists at that line number. :(